# How to add picture behind my appbar and have it show slightly but very blurred. To give the appbar a different look

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to follow a design for practice on flutter, but having some trouble with it. I added the same colors for the gradient as the design I have found, but I am not sure how to add those purpleish part. Somehow it is also transparent and displays an image behind the nav bar.

So my question is, how do I add an image behind my app bar and have it show just a little like in the first picture, so it makes this cool effect.
Or is there any other way to do it?
The designer also used a transparent gradient for one of the containers that shows part of the background picture but blurred out.

I have already set the routes and icons and all. Just want this effect

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return BottomAppBar(
     color: Color(0xFF1F1F1F),

     child: Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
           gradient: LinearGradient(
               begin: Alignment.topLeft,
               end: Alignment.bottomRight,
               colors: [
             Color(0xFF838383).withOpacity(0.7),
             Color(0xFF838383).withOpacity(0.4),
           ],
               stops: [
             0.0,
             1.0
           ])),
       height: 70,
       child: Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
         children: [
           IconButton(
             onPressed: () {
               Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
             },
             icon: Icon(
               Icons.home,
               color: Colors.white,
             ),
           ),
```

**App Bar, I am trying to create**

[image: App Bar I am trying to create]

**My appbar**

[image: My appbar]

**Container with same effect**

[image: Container with same effect]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using AppBar or BottomAppBar, you can create your own widget like using Container and adding a Row in it and adding icon in it, which will be wrapped with GestureDetector to detect taps.

```
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.home,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.home,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

You can wrap it with Stack and add an Image bellow or use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/blur) to blur the image and add an widget above